# Getting error in the c Program regarding expected ; before token

Tags: c, expression, token, geany

```
error: expected expression before ';' token 
graph[ ptr->count ].count- ;
                           ^
```

I am getting the error shown when I compile my code in Geany.  Can anyone please help what to do?

Comment: `What to do?` - try posting some code first. Also, `....count- ;` is missing the RHS of the `-`.

Comment: graph[ ptr->count ].count-- ;    //<< this should at least compile clean

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you’re trying to decrement...count by 1...you need one more minus sign, like this

```
int i = 10;
i--;
```

to be a valid expression in C/C++.

Comment: This is a typo question - this answer should rather be a comment and the whole question flagged for closure.